# Meteor.isCordova Folder

Tags: meteor

The ability meteor gives through its interaction with cordova to create mobile applications is incredible. I have one question however concerning the file structure: (https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp). There is no documentation concerning a folder specific to Cordova. As I have been writing my application, it seems incredibly tedious to use `if (Meteor.isCordova)` for any segment of code that I want specific functionality for the mobile app. I tried creating a top level folder `cordova` such as is already done with `client`, `server` etc... and removing the Meteor.isCordova wrapping my js code, but that process was unsuccessful. Is there a way to do what I am trying to do just in a different manner?

Comment: Hi nate, unfortunately right now there is no special folder for cordova-only code. The easiest way to designate a set of files as mobile-app only is to make a package.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no special folder for code which should only run on mobile. However it is a nice feature and I have created an issue on [GItHub](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3409). If you'd like to see this feature, I'd encourage you to comment on it.